# How to access property of an object in Laravel PHP?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I am having 2 methods. In one of the method I am making a call to database, a pure and simple one *Document::findOrFail($data->id)*. But this is always returning me *null* although a record is already persisted. Any idea how to get this simple thing sorted?

```
public function lockExport(Request $request){

    $document = Document::create([
     'user_id' => $this->userId(),
     'extension' => $extension,
     'name' => $filename,
     'file_path' => $filepath,
     'size' => File::size($filepath . $filename),
     'received_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')
   ]);
   $isAttachment = false;

   Cache::put($token, ['file' => $document->file_path . $document->name . '.' . $document->extension, 'is_attachment' => $isAttachment, 'id' => $document->id], 3);

   return $this->downloadlockExport($token);
}
```

```
public function downloadlockExport($token)
{
    try {

        $data = (object) Cache::get($token);
        // dd I get the full $data as object

        $document = Document::findOrFail($data->id);

        // undefined. Above query did not execute. 
        // Thus, below query failed
        $document->update(['downloads' => $document->downloads + 1]);

        $content = Crypt::decrypt(File::get($data->file));

        return response()->make($content, 200, array(
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . basename($data->file) . '"'
        ));

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        \App::abort(404);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably would like to do is:

```
public function lockExport(Request $request){

    $document = Document::create([
     'user_id' => $this->userId(),
     'extension' => $extension,
     'name' => $filename,
     'file_path' => $filepath,
     'size' => File::size($filepath . $filename),
     'received_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')
   ]);
   $isAttachment = false;

   $token = 'mytoken';
   Cache::put($token, ['file' => $document->file_path . $document->name . '.' . $document->extension, 'is_attachment' => $isAttachment, 'id' => $document->id], 3);

   return $this->downloadlockExport($token);
}
```

This way you will get your $token in your called function and you will get the $data correctly as I see.

And in the `downloadlockExport()` function you will have the ID like this:

```
$document = Document::findOrFail($data->mytoken['id']);
```

or you can use:

```
$document = Document::findOrFail($data->$token['id']);
```

similar with getting the File value:

```
$content = Crypt::decrypt(File::get($data->$token['file']));
```

Comment: Thanks Zollie for your answer. Your approach worked perfectly. But I am still curious to know why my simple approach did not work? Like defining an extra variable is an overhead `$token = 'mytoken';` So why could I not achieve this without defining.

Comment: You’re welcome. The $token variable in that case had to be defined within the function and it must be a string, since the `put()` method requires it that way as its first argument as a `’key’` in the cache (it could be any string but had to be defined). I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Perfect. Understood. Thanks a ton!